# How can I find all the commits that have more than one parent in a Git repository?

Tags: git

I am working on a research to study merges in open source projects.

For each merge in the repo I need to find the base (nearest common ancestor), the two contributors, and the resulting merged commit.

I already have an idea of how to get the nearest common ancestor (`git merge-base rev1 rev2`) and the contributors (`git log --pretty=%P -n 1 <commit>`), but I am having problem identifying the commits that resulted from a merge operation.

How can I find all the commits that have more than one parent in a Git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough (for local commit)

```
 git rev-list --merges
```

The [`git rev-list` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) mentions:

```
--merges
```

> **Print only merge commits**. This is exactly the same as `--min-parents=2`.

That means rev-list has some interesting filters:

```
--min-parents=<number>
--max-parents=<number>
```

> Show only commits which have at least (or at most) that many commits.
>   In particular:
>
> - `--max-parents=1` is the same as `--no-merges`,
> - `--min-parents=2` is the same as `--merges`.
> - `--max-parents=0` gives all **root commits** and
> - `--min-parents=3` all **octopus merges**.

Comment: Hi VonC, thank you for your answer. I am getting this error with your first command: "fatal: --merge without MERGE_HEAD?"

Comment: @macrobug sorry, it was a typo: it is `--merges`, not `--merge`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git log --merges
```

with the appropriate `--pretty` to parse the output.